# Pseudo classes & classes in CSS

Tags: css, html, class, pseudo-class

I am a new learner of CSS. 
There's something I'm doing wrong, regarding the pseudo classes because my code doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
ul.navigationbar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

li.navigationbar {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

a.navigationbar:link, a.navigationbar:visited {
display: block;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #98bf21;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.navigationbar:hover, a.navigationbar:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="navigationbar">
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Proveedores</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Artículos</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone that can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: what seems to be the issue?

Comment: What exactly `doesn't work`?

Comment: and make sure that if someone's answer is correct, mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 .navigationbar a:link {
/*some styles*/
}
```

and

```
 .navigationbar a:visited {
/*some styles*/
}
```

because the `a` is a child element of `.navigationbar`

Answer (score 0):

This `a.navigationbar:link, a.navigationbar:visited` is not working beacause
   the class `navigationbar` is assigned to the list element`li` in your markup not to the anchor `a` element.

```
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
```

to solve this change it to

```
[role=presentation] a:link, [role=presentation] a:visited
```

or to

```
li.navigationbar a:link, li.navigationbar a:visited
```

Here is the final demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style>
ul.navigationbar {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}

li.navigationbar {
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

li.navigationbar a:link, li.navigationbar a:visited {
display: block;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #98bf21;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 4px;
        text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.navigationbar:hover, a.navigationbar:active {
background-color: #7A991A;
}</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="navigationbar">
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Proveedores</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Artículos</a></li>
<li class="navigationbar" role="presentation"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```